# Type signature of a function to find the magnitude of a vector

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, typeclass

The following type signature to find the magnitude of a vector represented as a tuple doesn't seem to work:

```
mag :: (Floating b, Num a) => (a,a) -> b
mag (x,y) = sqrt (x**2 + y**2)
```

The error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `b' against inferred type `a'
  `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for `mag' at tone.hs:1:17
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for `mag' at tone.hs:1:24
In the expression: sqrt (x ** 2 + y ** 2)
In the definition of `mag': mag (x, y) = sqrt (x ** 2 + y ** 2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to compute a type signature is to ask the compiler to do the type inference for you:

```
Prelude> let mag (x,y) = sqrt (x**2 + y**2)

Prelude> :t mag
mag :: Floating a => (a, a) -> a
```

This is probably the type you want.

---

Now, your type takes a pair of a's and somehow converts them to a b in the `Num` class. Do you mean to have a conversion to the more general `Num` class there? If so, you'll need `truncate` or some thing like it, and a `fromIntegral`.

My guess is that this isn't what you want, but you can do it,

```
Prelude> let mag (x,y) = fromIntegral . truncate $ sqrt (x**2 + y**2)

Prelude> :t mag
mag :: (Floating a, RealFrac a, Floating a) => (a, a) -> c
```

Comment: Yes, I meant to have a conversion there. And thanks, the fromIntegral worked like a charm (without a truncation).

Comment: The requirement was to have a Floating magnitude for two Integral numbers. The use of fromIntegral and (Floating b, Integral a) works.

Comment: Style point: mostly Haskell doesn't put arguments in brackets like other languages; this would normally have the type "mag :: a -> a -> a".  I can see that here you probably want to treat a vector as an (x,y) pair, so a tuple makes sense.  But in that case you should document it using a type synonym: "type Vector a = (a,a)"

Comment: For this conversion, you should be doing "sqrt $ fromIntegral (x^2 + y^2).  The (^) operator takes an integral second argument, and is generally preferable to the (**) operator unless you need fractional exponents.  In this case you might be even better off just saying "x*x" etc.